# make visible ProgressBar from another class

Tags: android

I want to display ProgressBar of MainActivity from another class.

Here is Layout xml file of MainActivity and java class name is main.java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0844aa"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

And default is invisible for ProgressBar. But I want to make "visible" this ProgressBar from another class called **"subclass.java"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a BaseActivity and have the both class extend it.

Comment: Hi Kavin, can you give an example of this with some code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an Interface (implemented by Activity class) to subclass's constructor(or a setter method). In the interface, define methods to manipulate the progress bar.